# After inserting to the table, digits after decimal point changes to 0

Tags: sql, vertica, sqldatatypes

While SELECT'ing columns in Vertica, it shows normal numeric values:

> SELECT nvl2(exposure_time_ms, ROUND(exposure_time_ms / 1000, CASE WHEN exposure_time_ms < 10000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) :: numeric(12,1) AS exposure_seconds

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjwM3.png)

But when I am inserting the same thing to the table, which has column 'exposure seconds'  type NUMERIC(12,1), it changes all digits after the decimal point to 0:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNhnM.png)

Comment: Can you post what value exposure_time_ms contains? Also show us the insert query?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, this is because the `nvl2()` calculation produces an integer.  So, try this:

```
SELECT nvl2(exposure_time_ms,
            ROUND(exposure_time_ms / 1000.0,
                  CASE WHEN exposure_time_ms < 10000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                 ), 0
           )::numeric(12,1) AS exposure_seconds
```

I will say that it really doesn't make sense to round the values based on the magnitude.  You should store the value "as is" and use rounding for presentation -- if it is really needed.

Comment: It was not the issue with rounding or nvl2 function (while selecting it was showing correct numbers), so I changed column type from numeric (12,1) to decimal (12,1) and it works fine now. Not sure why though.